# 3D plane plot with wireframes matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a 3d plot that contains two wireframes of half sheres and a point:
[image]

now i want to add to it a plane that touches both the point and the tops of the wireframes.
the point is at [0,0,0].

the first sphere is centered at [4.73 , 4.73 , 0] with radius r = 0.29

the second shpere is centered at [0, 9.46 , 0] with radius r = 2.176

This is the code i have so far. Anyone can suggest how to add the plane in the same plot?

```
theta, phi = np.linspace(0,  np.pi, 10), np.linspace(0,2* np.pi, 13)
THETA, PHI = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
 
R2 = r_2 
X2 = R2 * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI) + x_in[1] 
Y2 = R2 *np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI) + y_in[1]
Z2 = R2 *np.absolute(np.cos(THETA))

R3 = r_3
X3 = R3 * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI) + x_in[2]
Y3 = R3 *np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI) + y_in[2]
Z3 = R3 *np.absolute(np.cos(THETA))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
plot = ax.plot_wireframe(X2, Y2, Z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=1,antialiased=False,\
       alpha=1)
plot = ax.plot_wireframe(X3, Y3, Z3, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=1, antialiased=False,\
       alpha=1)




ax.scatter(x_in[0] , y_in[0] , 0,  color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Comment: are you asking about the math or the programming?

Comment: About the math, I think the plane equation should be: 7.5207x -10.2641y + 44.74z =0. Buy i am having a bit of trouble plotting it in the same meshgrid as the spheres. Or at least when i plot it , it doesn't seem to touch the spheres at all

Comment: I would then ask on MathOverflow as you seem to have the programming well covered